# Locked out of my own blog and password reset not working

Tags: email, password

I have my own Wordpress installation for my infrequently updated blog.

I have a habit of forgetting my password so have to request a new one and reset it every two to three months.

I've done it again today and got the "Password Reset" e-mail (which arrives within seconds of requesting it). Following the link to actually reset the password gives me the "Check your e-mail for your new password." page but that e-mail never arrives.

I've checked my spam folder and there's nothing in that.

What's the quickest way of resetting my password and getting back into my blog? Do I have to go via the database? If so what do I need to reset there?

I should add that the blog hasn't been hacked - I've checked the pages and they're all OK. No spurious links or content vandalised.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can get to phpMyAdmin (or something equivalent), open the DB and find the wp_users table. Select the appropriate user to edit and change the user_pass field to `whatever`. Set the function to MD5 and save. You should now be able to log in.

Comment: Thanks - I wasn't sure that it would accept a plain text password.

Comment: It doesn't. I think PHPMyAdmin hashes it to MD5 before storing, which was what the MD5 was all about.

Answer (score 2):

Codex has good article [Resetting Your Password](http://codex.wordpress.org/Resetting_Your_Password) with multiple ways to do it.